# Multithreading / Asynchronous I/O

Tags: python, multithreading, io, urllib2

I have a conceptual question.

I currently have a programme that performs within a never ending loop.

```
Def (mycode):

    Perform login to server and retrieve cookies etc
    While 1:
      Perform an URL request (with custom headers, cookies etc)
      Process the reply
      Perform URL requests dependent upon the values in replies
      Process reply
```

I am happy for this to continue as it is, as the URL's must be called one after the other.

Now the server limits a single account to a limited number of functions, it would be useful to be able to perform this function with two (or more) different accounts.

My question is: Is this possible to do? I have done a reasonable amount of reading on queues and multithreading, if you nice people could suggest a method with a good (easy to understand) example I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Are you fetching the same url at step#1 each time ? in effect polling the page ? then acting on it's results differently.

Comment: Not exactly the same. I would be fetching www.foo.com/type=car and then maybe changing the params slightly for a different account

Answer (score 0):

[Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html) is a performant green threads implementation that has example.

I'm unsure if by doing this for different accounts to the same server you mean having different worker functions handling the url processing - in effect having `Def (mycode)` `n` times for each account. Perhaps you could expand on the detail.

```
>>> import gevent
>>> from gevent import socket
>>> urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
>>> jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]
>>> gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
>>> [job.value for job in jobs]
['74.125.79.106', '208.77.188.166', '82.94.164.162']
```

In addition you could break up the problem by using something like [beanstalkd](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/) which would allow you to run your main process 'n' times for each account and put the results on a beanstalk-queue for processing by another process.
Saves having to deal with threading which is always a good thing in non-trivial applications.

Comment: I don't mean worker functions. Only a single account can download each link.

It is more having one account working on a section (i.e. type=car, whilst another works on type=horse)

Comment: This is similar perhaps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905800/multiprocessing-useless-with-urllib2

Comment: Possibly, I did look at that example. What I am not sure about is how to handle the different cookies being passed.

Comment: Well I can only suggest you get a function that does what you want first and then worry about making it multithreaded. If you find that it's too difficult to do m/t because of the cookies then look into making it multiprocess perhaps using beanstalkd to communicate with. Also this question looks into cookies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage outside my comfort zone. :D

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I do have the function performing correctly. It works just fine with a single account, which is why I am now looking into multithreading. I'll carry on reading and see what I can figure out.

Comment: http://pythonquirks.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/asynchronous-http-request.html has a useful example, as with most examples they never cover all that you might want to do. I think it gives a flavour of it though.